# Fine Uploader, when cancelling an in-progress file, any other queued files remain in stasis until I add something else

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using the API rather than the UI. In my test I drag two video files into my drag and drop area, and while the first is uploading, I cancel it using

```
uploader.cancel(id);
```

I'd expect the second file to then begin uploading, but it doesn't, and there doesn't seem to be any way to kickstart it. I've tried

```
uploader.getInProgress()
```

and I'm told there's one file in progress, but Firebug shows there's no activity. However, if I now add a third file, that file starts uploading immediately, and when it's finished, the second one does finally start uploading.

How can I get the second file to start the moment I cancel the first? I've tried

```
uploader.uploadStoredFiles()
```

but this reports that there are no files to upload.

I'm using chunking and simultaneous uploads.

**Update**

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong, so I'll update this original question with a bit more code and perhaps @ray-nicholus can let me know if it needs reporting to GitHub instead.

Html on the page:

```
            <fieldset>
                <div id="thumbnaildrop" class="dragDropArea">

                    <article class="assetSet">

                        <ul class="thumbnailset jq-thumbnailset" id="thumbnailset">
                        </ul>    

                    </article>

                </div>

                <div class="uploadProgress">
                    <div class="uploadProgressBar"></div>
                    <div class="uploadProgressText">Uploading...</div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset style="margin-top:4px;">
                <div class="fileselect">
                    <div style="padding: 2px 5px; vertical-align: bottom; position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;" class="msgButton" id="addfiles">Add files<input style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0; height: 100%;" name="qqfile" multiple="" title="file input" qq-button-id="efa667dc-040e-4f4d-9436-5d90d531c4cf" type="file"></div>
                    <span id="dragdropmsg" class="adminAdvice jq-dragdropmsg">&nbsp;or drag and drop files into the panel above</span>
                    <button style="display: none;" id="cancelupload">Cancel uploading</button>

                    <script src="/Scripts/shared/all.fine-uploader/all.fine-uploader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Shared/Views/FineUploaderSupport.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    fineUploaderSupport.init({
        uploadUrl: "/SessionReadOnly/FineUploader",
        successUrl: "/Uploads/FineUploaderComplete",
        thumbnailQueuedUrl: "/Content/shared/images/placeholderqueued.gif",
        thumbnailUploadingPlaceholder: "/Content/shared/images/placeholderuploading.gif"
    }, {
        $cancelEl: $("#cancelupload"),
        $thumbTemplate: $("#newthumbTemplate"),
        $additionEl: $("#FilesToAddFromTempUploads"),
        browseButtonId: "addfiles",
        dropZoneId: "thumbnaildrop",
        $thumbDestnEl: $("#thumbnailset"),
        $filesTooBigId: $("#filesTooBigAlert")
    }, {
        imageFiles: "Image files",
        movieFiles: "Movie files",
        documents: "Documents",
        zipFiles: "Zip files",
        progressBarMessage: "{size} of {totalSize} at {speed}/s ({time} remaining)",
        progressBarCompleteMessage: "{totalSize} uploaded in {time}",
        oneSecond: "1 second",
        xSeconds: "{quantity} seconds",
        oneMinute: "1 minute",
        xMinutes: "{quantity} minutes",
        oneHour: "1 hour",
        xHours: "{quantity} hours"

    }, {
        maxFiles: 0,
        filesAddedFunc: "filesUpload.clearZeroAssetError",
        replaceContent: false,
        uploadComplete: "",
        maxFileSizeBytes: 2147483648,
        allowedExtensions: "7z,ai,avi,bmp,div,divx,doc,docx,eps,f4v,flv,gif,indd,jpeg,jpg,m4v,mif,mkv,mov,mp3,mp4,mpeg,mpg,mts,mv4,mxf,pdf,png,pps,ppsx,ppt,pptx,psb,psd,rar,rtf,sbv,tga,tif,tiff,txt,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip",
        debug: true
    }, {
        folder: "2015/09/22174452-c59a5243-607d-4143-bc16-4acc89300d59",
        width: "200",
        height: ""
    });
});
</script>

<script id="newthumbTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
<li class=tn>
        <div data-guid="2643e378-f8d6-4a3b-936e-d9f4914acfa2" title="Delete" class="thumbnailDelete"> </div> <div class="thumbnailDelete new" title="Delete" data-url="${TemporaryFilename}" data-origsz="${TotalOriginalSize}"> </div>
    <img src="${ThumbnailUrl}" alt="new thumb" class="imagingThumb ${Classes}" />
    <div class="thumbnailFilename" style="width:200px">
        <div>${DisplayFilename}</div>
        <div>${DisplayText}</div>
    </div>
    <span class="tn-progress jq-tn-progress"></span>
</li>
</script>
```

My support script, fineUploaderSupport.js:

```
var fineUploaderSupport = {
uploader: null,
elements: {},
urls: {},
translations: {},
options: {},
extraParams: {},
dragAndDropModel: null,
totalAdded: 0,
percentComplete: 0,
startTime: 0,
updateUploadProgressTimeout: false,
$uploadProgress: null,
elapsedTime: 0,
idPrefix: "upld-",

init: function (urls, elements, translations, options, extraParams) {

    fineUploaderSupport.elements = elements;
    fineUploaderSupport.urls = urls;
    fineUploaderSupport.translations = translations;
    fineUploaderSupport.options = options;
    if (typeof fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFiles === "undefined")
        fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFiles = 0;
    fineUploaderSupport.extraParams = extraParams;

    if (typeof elements.$thumbTemplate !== "undefined")
        $.template("thumbnailTemplate", elements.$thumbTemplate); // Cache the template
    elements.$cancelEl.hide();
    elements.$additionEl.val(""); // Reset additions in case FF has kept old values

    var filters = { mime_types: [] };
    if (typeof options.allowedExtensions !== "undefined" && options.allowedExtensions !== "") {
        filters.mime_types.push({ title: "Supported files", extensions: options.allowedExtensions });
    }

    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress = $("#" + elements.dropZoneId).siblings(".uploadProgress");

    fineUploaderSupport.uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
        debug: options.debug,
        button: document.getElementById(elements.browseButtonId),
        maxConnections: 10,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: options.allowedExtensions.split(",")
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: urls.uploadUrl,
            minSizeLimit: options.minSizeLimit || 100,
            sizeLimit: options.maxFileSizeBytes,
            params: {
                folder: extraParams.folder,
                width: extraParams.width,
                height: extraParams.height
            }
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true,
            showButton: true
        },
        chunking: {
            partSize: 1048576,
            enabled: true,
            mandatory: true,
            concurrent: {
                enabled: true
            },
            success: {
                endpoint: urls.successUrl
            }
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        callbacks: {
            onSubmit: fineUploaderSupport.onFileAdded,
            onAllComplete: fineUploaderSupport.onAllComplete,
            onProgress: fineUploaderSupport.onProgress,
            onError: fineUploaderSupport.onError,
            onComplete: fineUploaderSupport.onComplete,
            onTotalProgress: fineUploaderSupport.onTotalProgress
        },
        thumbnails: {
            maxCount: 50
        }
    });

    /* If supports drag-and-drop; still looking for most reliable way to test this */
    if (qq.supportedFeatures.fileDrop) {
        fineUploaderSupport.dragAndDropModule = new qq.DragAndDrop({
            dropZoneElements: [document.getElementById(elements.dropZoneId)],
            classes: {
                dropActive: "dropped"
            },
            callbacks: {
                processingDroppedFiles: function() {
                },
                processingDroppedFilesComplete: function(files) {
                    fineUploaderSupport.uploader.addFiles(files); //this submits the dropped files to Fine Uploader
                }
            }
        });

        // Add mouseover effect to drag and drop area
        $("#" + elements.dropZoneId).show()
            .on("dragover", function() {
                $(this).addClass("dropableAbove").removeClass("dropped");
            })
            .on("dragleave", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("dropableAbove");
            })
            .on("drop", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("dropableAbove").addClass("dropped");
            });

        // Set up the cancel all button
        if (fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl)
            fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl.on("click.cancelButton", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).fadeOut("fast");
                fineUploaderSupport.uploader_cancelAll();
                $(".pluploadinqueue").fadeOut(function () { $(this).remove(); });

                return false;
            });
    }
},

formatSize: function (size) {

    if (typeof size === "undefined" || /\D/.test(size)) {
        return "N/A";
    }

    function round(num, precision) {
        return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
    }

    var boundary = Math.pow(1024, 4);

    // TB
    if (size > boundary) {
        return round(size / boundary, 1) + " TB";
    }

    // GB
    if (size > (boundary /= 1024)) {
        return round(size / boundary, 1) + " GB";
    }

    // MB
    if (size > (boundary /= 1024)) {
        return round(size / boundary, 1) + " MB";
    }

    // KB
    if (size > 1024) {
        return Math.round(size / 1024) + " kB";
    }

    return size + " b";
},

onFileAdded: function (id, filename) {
    var fileSize = fineUploaderSupport.uploader.getSize(id);

    if (typeof fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFileSizeBytes !== "undefined") {
        if (fileSize > fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFileSizeBytes) {
            if (fineUploaderSupport.elements.$filesTooBigId !== "undefined" && fineUploaderSupport.elements.$filesTooBigId.length > 0)
                MSG.showNHide(fineUploaderSupport.elements.$filesTooBigId, null);
            else
                alert(filename + " is too large to upload through the browser. Please use FTP instead.");

            return false;
        }
    }

    if (fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFiles > 0 && fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded >= fineUploaderSupport.options.maxFiles) {
        return false;
    }
    fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded++;

    if (fineUploaderSupport.startTime === 0 || fineUploaderSupport.uploader.getInProgress() === 0) { // It's the start of a new upload
        fineUploaderSupport.startTime = new Date();
    }

    fineUploaderSupport.uploader_showCancelButton();

    if (typeof fineUploaderSupport.options.filesAddedFunc !== "undefined" && fineUploaderSupport.options.filesAddedFunc !== "")
        executeFunctionByName(fineUploaderSupport.options.filesAddedFunc, window);

    if (typeof fineUploaderSupport.elements.$thumbTemplate !== "undefined") {
        var $newThumb = $.tmpl("thumbnailTemplate", {
            ThumbnailUrl: fineUploaderSupport.urls.thumbnailQueuedUrl,
            DisplayFilename: filename,
            DisplayText: fineUploaderSupport.formatSize(fileSize)
        }).attr("id", fineUploaderSupport.idPrefix + id).addClass("pluploadinqueue");

        if (fineUploaderSupport.options.replaceContent) {
            fineUploaderSupport.elements.$thumbDestnEl.empty().prepend($newThumb);
        } else {
            $newThumb.appendTo(fineUploaderSupport.elements.$thumbDestnEl);
        }

        if (qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews) {
            var width = fineUploaderSupport.extraParams.width;
            var $img = $newThumb.find("img:first").css("opacity","0.5");
            fineUploaderSupport.uploader.drawThumbnail(id, $img[0], width, false);
        }

        // Scroll to upload position
        var $thumbnailDrop = $("#" + fineUploaderSupport.elements.dropZoneId);
        $thumbnailDrop.animate({ scrollTop: $thumbnailDrop[0].scrollHeight });
    }

    MSG.showNHide(fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress, null);
    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress.find(".uploadProgressBar:first").show();

    return true;
},

onAllComplete: function (succeeded) {

    var totalUploaded = 0;
    $.each(succeeded, function (i, file) {
        totalUploaded += fineUploaderSupport.uploader.getSize(file);
    });
    fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgressComplete(totalUploaded, fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime);
    fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime = 0; // Reset in case further files added

    fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl.unbind("click.cancelButton").fadeOut("fast");

    if (fineUploaderSupport.options.replaceContent)
        fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded = 0; // if we're replacing rather than appending, reset the count on completion

    if (typeof fineUploaderSupport.options.uploadComplete !== "undefined")
        executeFunctionByName(fineUploaderSupport.options.uploadComplete, window, fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded);

    $.each(fineUploaderSupport.uploader_oncomplete, function () {
        this(fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded);
    });

},

onProgress: function(id, filename, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
    var percent = uploadedBytes / totalBytes * 100;
    $("#" + fineUploaderSupport.idPrefix + id + " .jq-tn-progress").html(Math.floor(percent) + "%");
    $.each(fineUploaderSupport.uploader_onprogress, function () {
        this(percent);
    });
},

onError: function(id, name, errorReason) {
    fineUploaderSupport.displayError(name + ": " + errorReason);
},

onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        // It's finished uploading; fade out the placeholder and fade in the new thumb
        var $newthumb = $.tmpl("thumbnailTemplate", responseJSON.UploadedThumbnails);
        $("#" + fineUploaderSupport.idPrefix + id).fadeOut("fast", function () { $(this).before($newthumb.fadeIn("fast")).remove(); });
        $.each(responseJSON.UploadedThumbnails, function (i, t) {
            if (fineUploaderSupport.options.replaceContent)
                fineUploaderSupport.elements.$additionEl.val(t.TemporaryFilename);
            else {
                fineUploaderSupport.elements.$additionEl.appendVal("*" + t.TemporaryFilename);

                if (typeof filesUpload !== "undefined")
                    filesUpload.UpdateSizeOfUploadedFiles(t.TotalOriginalSize);
            }
        });
        $.each(responseJSON.RejectedFiles, function (j, t) {
            fineUploaderSupport.error(t);
        });
    } else {
        fineUploaderSupport.uploader_cancelone(id);
        fineUploaderSupport.error(name + ": " + responseJSON.ErrorMessage);
    }
},

displayError: function (msg) {
    MSG.showNHide($(".jq-pluploaderror").show().append("<div>" + msg + "</div>"), null);
},

uploader_showCancelButton: function () {
    if (fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl.has(":hidden")) {
        fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl.fadeIn();
    }
},

uploader_cancelAll: function () {
    fineUploaderSupport.uploader.cancelAll();
    fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded = 0;
    fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime = 0;
    MSG.removeButtonLoading();
    MSG.showNHide(null, fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress);
    fineUploaderSupport.elements.$cancelEl.unbind("click.cancelButton").fadeOut("fast");
},

uploader_cancelone: function (id) {
    id = id.replace(fineUploaderSupport.idPrefix, ""); // cos the id might have our prefix
    fineUploaderSupport.uploader.cancel(id);
    fineUploaderSupport.totalAdded--;
    $("#" + fineUploaderSupport.idPrefix + id).fadeOut("fast", function () { $(this).remove(); });
    MSG.removeButtonLoading();
    //alert("progress: " + fineUploaderSupport.uploader.getInProgress());
    if (!fineUploaderSupport.uploader_currentlyuploading()) {
        fineUploaderSupport.uploader_cancelAll();
    } else {
        alert("it won't continue");
    }
},

uploader_currentlyuploading: function () {
    return fineUploaderSupport.uploader.getInProgress() > 0;
},

onTotalProgress: function(totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
    fineUploaderSupport.percentComplete = totalUploadedBytes / totalBytes * 100;
    if (!fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgressTimeout) {
        fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgressTimeout = true;
        fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgress(totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes);
        setTimeout(function () { fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgressTimeout = false }, 2000);
    }
},

uploader_percentagecomplete: function () {
    return Math.floor(fineUploaderSupport.percentComplete);
},

uploader_oncomplete: [],

uploader_onprogress: [],

updateUploadProgress: function (totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes) {

    var ETA = 0, uploadSpeed = 0;

    fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime = new Date() - fineUploaderSupport.startTime;
    if (fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime > 0) {
        uploadSpeed = totalUploadedBytes / fineUploaderSupport.elapsedTime;
    }
    if (uploadSpeed > 0) {
        ETA = ((totalBytes - totalUploadedBytes) / uploadSpeed);
    }

    fineUploaderSupport.updateUploadProgressBar(totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes, uploadSpeed, ETA);
},

updateUploadProgressBar: function (totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes, speed, ETA) {
    var uploadProgressText = fineUploaderSupport.translations.progressBarMessage
        .replace("{size}", fineUploaderSupport.formatSize(totalUploadedBytes))
        .replace("{totalSize}", fineUploaderSupport.formatSize(totalBytes))
        .replace("{speed}", fineUploaderSupport.formatSize(Math.round(speed * 1000)))
        .replace("{time}", fineUploaderSupport.approxTime(ETA));

    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress.find(".uploadProgressBar:first").css("width", fineUploaderSupport.percentComplete + "%");
    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress.find(".uploadProgressText:first").text(uploadProgressText);
},

updateUploadProgressComplete: function (totalBytes, uploadTime) {
    var uploadProgressText = fineUploaderSupport.translations.progressBarCompleteMessage
        .replace("{totalSize}", fineUploaderSupport.formatSize(totalBytes))
        .replace("{time}", fineUploaderSupport.displayTime(uploadTime));

    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress.find(".uploadProgressBar:first").hide();
    fineUploaderSupport.$uploadProgress.find(".uploadProgressText:first").text(uploadProgressText);
},

displayTime: function (time) {
    var seconds = Math.round(time / 1000),
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0,
    timestring = "";

    if (seconds > 60) {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds = seconds - (minutes * 60);
    }

    if (minutes > 60) {
        hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        minutes = minutes - (hours * 60);
    }

    if (seconds === 1) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneSecond;
    else if (seconds > 0) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xSeconds.replace("{quantity}", seconds);

    if (minutes === 1) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneMinute + " " + timestring;
    else if (minutes > 0) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xMinutes.replace("{quantity}", minutes) + " " + timestring;

    if (hours === 1) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneHour + " " + timestring;
    else if (hours > 0) timestring = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xHours.replace("{quantity}", hours) + " " + timestring;

    return timestring;

},

approxTime: function (time) {

    time = Math.round(time / 1000); // Convert to seconds;
    var singularUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneSecond;
    var pluralUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xSeconds;

    if (time > 30) {
        time = Math.round(time / 5) * 5;
        if (time >= 60) {
            time = Math.round(time / 60);
            singularUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneMinute;
            pluralUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xMinutes;
            if (time > 30) {
                time = Math.round(time / 5) * 5;
                if (time >= 60) {
                    time = Math.round(time / 60);
                    singularUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.oneHour;
                    pluralUnit = fineUploaderSupport.translations.xHours;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (time === 1) return singularUnit;

    return pluralUnit.replace("{quantity}", time);

}
}
```

Finally, the console output from FineUploader after selecting two video files, and cancelling the first during upload. (It's a local test, so was very quick. Despite me cancelling almost immediately it had done 19 chunks so I've cut out most of the debug messages, after checking if there was anything other than uploading success stuff in there.)

```
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Received 2 files. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to validate image. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to draw client-side image preview. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to determine if Family Escape HD7.mp4 can be rendered in this browser jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] First pass: check type attribute of blob object. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Family Escape HD7.mp4 is not previewable in this browser per the blob's type attr jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Not previewable jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 1-1048576 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 1048577-2097152 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 2097153-3145728 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 3145729-4194304 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 4194305-5242880 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 5242881-6291456 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 6291457-7340032 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 7340033-8388608 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 8388609-9437184 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 9437185-10485760 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to validate image. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to draw client-side image preview. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Attempting to determine if 'Mr. Plastimime' - Kickstarter Backer Preview7.mp4 can be rendered in this browser jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] First pass: check type attribute of blob object. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] 'Mr. Plastimime' - Kickstarter Backer Preview7.mp4 is not previewable in this browser per the blob's type attr jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Not previewable jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] xhr - server response received for 0 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] responseText = {

  "success": true

} jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Received response status 200 with body: {

  "success": true

} jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 8 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Chunk 8 for file 0 uploaded successfully. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 10485761-11534336 of 193230016 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] xhr - server response received for 0 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] responseText = {

  "success": true

} jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Received response status 200 with body: {

  "success": true

} jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 4 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Chunk 4 for file 0 uploaded successfully. jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591

(A bunch more successfull chunk messages but nothing else.)

[Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Cancelling 0 jquery-1.11.1.js line 338 > eval:16:2591
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to troubleshoot. Please provide all related code and log messages. Debug option should be enabled.

Comment: Also, stack overflow isn't for bug reports. If you think there is a bug in the library, please open an issue in the GitHub repo instead. Please include _all_ related code + debug logs as well.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if I was just doing something wrong or missing the correct command. I'll update.

Comment: I'm not able to determine exactly when the issue occurs in the log messages you posted. Also, your code appears to be several magnitudes more complex than I would expect for an integration with an upload library. I'm not able to read through all of it. I'll go ahead and test 5.3.2 on Monday and attempt to reproduce using the information you provided before your update.

Comment: Sorry about the complexity. We're still evaluating to decide whether to replace plupload with Fine Uploader, so switching one for the other is the easiest way for us to compare.

Comment: After some brief testing, I'm not seeing this issue locally. Your best bet is to attempt to reproduce by starting with the simplest possible set of code on your end, and the progressively add back the complexity until you are able to determine what is causing your issue. It's not clear whether this is an issue in Fine Uploader caused by some specific and relatively unique integration code on your end, or just a bug in your code. Once this is clear, I'll be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. Last night we confirmed that it's working fine with your demo code, so we also decided on the same action: start from your demo code and template, and try and make it look like our existing system as much as possible.

Comment: I've got it all working using the normal FineUploader (with templating) but I have managed to repeat what I think is a bug by implementing my own Cancel button and trying to call uploader.Cancel(id). It does cancel but doesn't start the next one. I'll submit a bug report to GitHub.